# Can a property of a ndb.Model be named “key” if it is never put in the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I have the following classes:

```
class Setting(ndb.Model):
    key = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, repeated=False)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, repeated=False)
    value = ndb.BooleanProperty(indexed=False, repeated=False, default=False)

class MessageSettings(ndb.Model):
    settings = ndb.StructuredProperty(Setting, indexed=False, repeated=True)
```

Of note, my `Setting` class has a field named `key`. In the `ndb` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#ndb-entity-models), however, it states:

> Don't name a property "key." This name is reserved for a special property used to store the Model key. Though it may work locally, a property named "key" will prevent deployment to App Engine.

This has not been my experience. I *can* deploy my application and my application executes as expected. That being said, I never explicitly put a `Setting` entity in the datastore.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at [`model.py`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/master/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py), specifically the [`Model`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/master/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#2783) class, we find that constructing an object is split between:

1. Objects that have been `put` in the datastore.
2. Object that have *not* been `put` in the datastore.

The former case *may* cause issues. Let’s see why this is the case:

When an `Model` object is first instantiated, its `key` is set to `None`. However, if the object has an attribute `key`, this is set to whatever is provided to the constructor when the object is instantiated.

Let’s say I pass the following `kwargs` to my `Setting` class:

```
kwargs = {
    'key': 'key',
    'name': 'name',
    'value': False,
}

s = Setting(**kwargs)
```

`s.key` would equal the string, `key`.

In the `Model` class, we find that a pseudo-property for the `key` is set:

```
_key = ModelKey()
key = _key
```

However, when the `Model` is instantiated, `key` is set to the value provided to the constructor when the object is instantiated. In such a case, `_key`, the `Model` pseudo-property for the `key`, is set to the `Key` object used to designate this entity:

```
self._key = Key(self._get_kind(), id,
    parent = parent, app = app, namespace = namespace)
```

A cursory search for the use of `self.key` reveals that it is not used in `put()`. The `get()` method is called on the `Key` object itself, so the `Model` class plays no role.

Given this, it would seem that the admonition:

> **Note**: you cannot define a property named *key*; the `.key` attribute always refers to the entity's key.  But you can define properties named *id* or *parent*.  Values for the latter cannot be passed through the constructor, but can be assigned to entity attributes after the entity has been created.

is well intended, but not fundamentally necessary.

In addition, since the class I created should never be explicitly `put` in the datastore, I simply defined a `_pre_put_hook` to raise an exception if this ever did occur:

```
def _pre_put_hook(self):
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot put entity {}.'.format(type(self).__name__))
```